# is possible to convert soap web services to xml format?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, web-services, soap

is possible to convert soap web services to xml format?

I want to use soap webservice in Iphone applications.

Comment: check this [tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/)

Answer (score 3):

```
is possible to convert soap web services to xml format?
```

From wikipedia:

> SOAP, originally defined as Simple Object Access Protocol, is a
>   protocol specification for exchanging structured information in the
>   implementation of Web Services in computer networks. It relies on
>   Extensible Markup Language (XML) for its message format (...)